# How to start apache2 at eth0 instead of docker0?

Tags: apache, apache2

```
service apache2 start
```

current resides randomly, and often start in `172.17.0.1`

```
└─# ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.87.131  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.87.255

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
```

However, somehow it could not be accessed through `eth0`, and I want to change the apache2 to be hosted at `eth0` or `192.168.87.131` so the other devices could access it.

I tried to change `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` by specifying `Listen 80` to

```
Listen 192.168.87.131
# or 
Listen 192.168.87.131:80
```

But this went into errors

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xeu apache2.service" for details.
```

which were

```
× apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-01-30 01:54:03 EST; 15s ago
   Duration: 10min 54.810s
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 16090 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 17ms

Jan 30 01:54:03 kali systemd[1]: Starting apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 30 01:54:03 kali apachectl[16092]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 5 of /etc/apache2/p>
Jan 30 01:54:03 kali apachectl[16092]: Port must be specified
Jan 30 01:54:03 kali systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, s>
Jan 30 01:54:03 kali systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 30 01:54:03 kali systemd[1]: Failed to start apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Serve>
lines 1-14/14 (END)
```

and

```
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit apache2.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Jan 30 01:54:03 kali systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit apache2.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 30 01:54:03 kali systemd[1]: Failed to start apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Serve>
░░ Subject: A start job for unit apache2.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit apache2.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 2304 and the job result is failed.
```

It went very bad that I had to purge apache2 and reinstall it to fix the module.

How to start `apache2` at `eth0` instead of `docker0`?